# Why is there only a box constraint on alpha and not on mu when solving the dual problem of soft linear SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, lagrange-multipliers

I am currently learning about the linear SVM in the non-separable case. In the dual representation, we introduce the Lagrange multipliers μ<sub>k</sub> and α<sub>k</sub> (see also this source: https://machinelearningmastery.com/method-of-lagrange-multipliers-the-theory-behind-support-vector-machines-part-2-the-non-separable-case/). Both my course notes and the above source say that the following should hold: c - μ<sub>k</sub> - α<sub>k</sub> = 0. But then without further explanation they go on and say 0 ≤ α<sub>k</sub> ≤ c. Since μ<sub>k</sub> is a Lagrange mulitplier and thus ≥ 0, how is the only a box constraint on α<sub>k</sub> sufficient?

Comment: the box constraint on $\alpha$ comes from (1) $\alpha\geq 0$, (2) $0=C-\alpha-\mu$ (3) $\mu\geq0$. We see that if all these constraints are to be satisfied, we will always have $0\leq\alpha\leq C$ (since $\alpha = C-\mu$).